# How to create a histogram chart in excel using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create histograms in multiple sheets of an excel workbook. I can very easily crate chart using pandas or matplotlib libraries and show it in python output window. However I would like to plot the histogram chart in excel. I am using office 360. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: this could help you  https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/bar.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a histogram chart with XlsxWriter using an Excel "Column" chart type: [Column chart example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_column.html)

[image]

See also the [Working with Charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs.